# Getting rid of 'via' in google mailing via Mailgun, DMARC, SPF and DKIM records

Tags: gmail, mailgun, spf, dkim, dmarc

I am using mailgun under the domain 'mg.mydomain.org' but I want emails send to be authenticated to my domain, lets say its 'mydomain'.

The settings below dont seem to work at all and I am still seeing the 'via' in gmail. Ive looked over the gmail docs and not got any further.

I am not experienced in setting up this type of configuration so if any more information is required to help ill be happy to provide

```
Dmarc record is currently : 
"v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:postmaster@mg.mydomain.com"

SPF record:
"v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"

DKIM record is generated from the mail client
"k=xxx; p=xxxxxx"
```

Thanks,

M

Comment: You'll want to eventually switch the `p=none` to `p=reject` - keeping it as none just allows you to get informational reports. I'm not sure if your example is a typo, but if your domain `mg.mydomain.org` and your dmarc rua domain is `mg.mydomain.com` - notice the .org and .com as the difference. This is going to require setting up a special DMARC record on the .com domain. You can test to ensure you have everything set up right by using [mailtest](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/email-authentication.html) or something similar.

Comment: Hi Henry, yeah was just a typo. Thanks for the point on p=reject. Will keeping it as none cause any issues or overheads if i am generating information reports?

Comment: There is no overhead on your side, only the ESP side that honor's the Record will have to do extra processing to evaluate and send the reports to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the "via" flag appears in gmail when the "From:" header in an email doesn't match the sending domain.

If you're using the Mailgun API, check that you're using the right sending domain.

Example:

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-abcd1234' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.mydomain.org/messages \
-F from='Me <me@mydomain.org>' \
-F to='my.account@gmail.com' \
-F subject='Hello' \
-F text='Testing'
```

In the example, the `from` domain is just the mydomain.org.  Gmail should still render it without the "via".